# dropdownlist onclick get options from database Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an order system in Asp.net mvc.

In order page I have 100 product in a list. And there is a size and color dropdownlist for each product.

This means that there are 200 dropdown lists on a page. All of these selectlist's options coming from database. If I write a query in controller, then send it from controller to view, it will be slow when page is loading. So, I want to find a solution for this problem. 
The first thing that comes to mind is this:

If a user click dropdownlist, dropdownlist will fill with options. I want to do it with ajax.

My codes are below:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ProductName</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <select id="select-size-@item.ID" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="0">Size</option>
                        @foreach (var size in item.ProductSizeList)
                        {
                            <option value="@size.ID">@size.SizeForOrder</option>
                        }
                    </select>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <select id="select-color-@item.ID" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="0">Color</option>
                        @foreach (var color in item.ProductColorList)
                        {
                            <option value="@color.ID">@color.ColorName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <input type="text" id="number-quantity-@item.ID" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="price-@item.ID"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-6"></div><a id="addtocart-@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Add to Cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cart-plus"></i>Add to Cart</a>
                <div class="col-6"><span id="result-@item.ID"></span></div>
            </td>

        </tr>
}

</tbody>
```

My ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <text>
          $('select#select-size-@(item.ID)').onchange(function() {
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                var variationId = $('select#select-size-@(item.ID)').val();
                var colorid = $('select#select-color-@(item.ID)').val();
                var link = "/Order/GetSizes/";
                var a = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: link,
                    data: {proId:variationId},
                    success: function (result) {
                        var ddl = $('select#select-size-@(item.ID)');
                        ddl.empty();
                        $.each(result, function(index,item){
                            ddl.append(
                                $('<option/>', {
                                    value: item.ID,
                                    text: item.SizeForOrder
                                })
                                );
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </text>
        }

    });
</script>
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Models.DTO.OrderDTO.NewOrderVM> orderlist = rpproduct.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.OwnerCategory.CreateDate).ThenBy(x => x.ProductName).Select(a => new Models.DTO.OrderDTO.NewOrderVM()
            {
                ID = a.Id,
                ProductName = a.ProductName,
                ProductSizeList = rpproduct.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == a.Id && y.IsDeleted == false).Variations.Where(z => z.IsDeleted == false).Select(b => new Models.DTO.VariationDTO.VariationVM()
                {
                    //ID = b.Id,
                    //SizeForOrder = b.Height + "-" + b.Width + "-" + b.Sections,
                    //Quantity = rpstock.Quantity(b.Id),
                }).ToList(),

                ProductColorList = rpproduct.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == a.Id && x.IsDeleted == false).Colors.Where(h => h.IsDeleted == false).Select(c => new Models.DTO.OrderDTO.ColorForOrderVM()
                {
                    //ID = c.ColorId,
                    //ColorName = c.Color.ColorName,
                }).ToList(),

            }).ToList();

            return View(orderlist);
        }

        public JsonResult GetSizes(int proId)
        {
            List<Models.DTO.VariationDTO.VariationVM> ProductSizeList = new List<Models.DTO.VariationDTO.VariationVM>();
            ProductSizeList = rpproduct.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == proId && x.IsDeleted == false).Variations.Where(y => y.IsDeleted == false).Select(b => new Models.DTO.VariationDTO.VariationVM()
            {
                ID = b.Id,
                SizeForOrder = b.Height + "-" + b.Width + "-" + b.Sections
            }).ToList();

            return Json(ProductSizeList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

How to populate dropdownlist's options from database with ajax using this dropdownlist's click event?

DropDownList will be empty when page first load. When the user click the arrow of the DropDownList, it will wait for a while and the DropDownList will be populated with the data from the database. Are there any example like this? Or how can I search it, I am bad in English so I couldn't find solution for this problem.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. And are you sure showing all products at once is good idea? I don't think I've ever seen that many on a page at once while shopping online.

Comment: I updated my question. Is not all ecommerce sites already like this? On the name, the productlist page.

Comment: I do not show the product pictures as a plus. I have only the product name, dropdownlist for the product sizes and dropdownlist for the product color in order page.